# Can't delete a folder due to it being open in System

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, storage, microsoft-store

I have been trying to delete the Halo MCC game files folder from my laptop, and I have the necessary permissions to do so however whenever I try to delete the folder it says it is unable to due to the folder being open in System. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried deleting it after booting windows in safe mode ?

Answer (score 3):

Its most likely saying that the file is open by the user SYSTEM, which indicates that a service has a lock in it.

It is likely that this game has a DRM protection or anti-cheat service running. The right way to remove the folder is to first uninstall the game using the installer, so all dependencies are uninstalled, then you can delete any leftover folders.

Comment: The thing is that I have already clicked uninstall on the game prior to this and i thought it was over and done with, and with Halo MCC there is no installer or anything like that.

Comment: If you have not rebooted after the uninstall, reboot first, then try to delete the folder.

Comment: I just attempted to delete the folder after a reboot and it still says that the 133GB file is open in System

Comment: Make a new User account, restart, log into the new User account and delete the folder from the new account.

Answer (score 0):

If it was installed through Steam, close it and stop the Steam background service. Resource monitor in task manager shows hard drive activity, but there are better programs for tracing the thread that has locked it

Answer (score 0):

Deleting in safe mode should work, while ur in safe mode, try finding services that interfere or actively use/lock the game files and disable them. You might also wanna try takeownershippro.

TLDR: close applications and services that may be using whatever you want to delete(make sure to system restore point first)